# Unable to configure JIRA in eclipse mylyn task

Tags: eclipse, mylyn, jira-agile

I am trying to configure atlassian JIRA eclipse plugin. Getting following error. Anyone has solution for this ?

[image: Eclipse error]

Comment: So which char is at index 53?

Answer (score 1):

File a bug against JIRA for not encoding spaces or remove the spaces in "ADAM M5 sub-story v3.jpg" if you have access to that file.